# Wcf Service to consume SOAP, plus Raw Xml and Json in .NET 4.5.1

Tags: c#, xml, json, wcf, soap

I have a Wcf service .NET 4.5.1 which I can connect to using the WcfTestClient.exe and send a test object, or (soap) Xml like using the following;

```
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <s:Header>
    <Action s:mustUnderstand="1" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2005/05/addressing/none">http://tempuri.org/IService/PostData</Action>
  </s:Header>
  <s:Body>
    <PostData xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
      <person xmlns:d4p1="PersonNameSpace" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
        <d4p1:Id>1</d4p1:Id>
        <d4p1:Name>My Name</d4p1:Name>
      </person>
    </PostData>
  </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

My interface is as follows;

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IService
{
    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "POST",
        UriTemplate = "PostData",
        RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Xml,
        BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare)]
    string PostData(Person person);
}

[DataContract(Namespace = "PersonNameSpace")]
public class Person
{
    [DataMember]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

With my method like below;

```
public string PostData(Person person)
{
    //do something with the object
    return "Well done";
}
```

This works fine.  But now, I'm wanting to call the same method PostData either by passing raw Xml or Json from a Classic ASP page as an example;

```
<PostData>
    <person>
      <Id>1</Id>        
      <Name>My name</Name>
    </person>
</PostData>
```

Or Json format as

```
{
  "PostData": {
    "person": {
      "Id": "1",
      "Name": "My name"
    }
  }
}
```

How can I consume this data as either Xml or Json, so that I can use either XmlSerializer or  something like;

> JavaScriptSerializer.Deserialize(PostDataString);

Basically what I'm wanting to do, is whether the request is from a application using SOAP, or a website using basic Xml posts, take this data and Deserialise it into my object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I suggest is you can open two endpoints, one for xml and the other for json. This is for better practise when using REST and also better for your client to consume.

```
[OperationContract]
[WebInvoke(Method = "POST", 
    ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Xml, 
    BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.WrappedRequest, 
    UriTemplate = "/PostDataXML")]
string PostDataXML(Person person);

[OperationContract]
[WebInvoke(Method = "POST",
    ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
    BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.WrappedRequest,
    UriTemplate = "/PostDataJSON")]
string PostDataJSON(Person person);
```

Then you simply need to post this object to your service:

```
{
  "person": {
    "Id": "1",
    "Name": "My name"
  }
}
```

Comment: Is this my only option, since I will have able 10 methods, which doubled up with be 20 in total

Comment: You can still assign the two webinvoke to the same operation contract. The two endpoints are just practise thing and you can find whatever that suits your model better.

Comment: I tried what you suggested, but am getting "System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found."

Comment: What is the URL you calling? You need to append /PostData after the svc file in the path, something like this: http://localhost/yourservice.svc/PostData

Comment: I'm trying to post from a C# console app to the correct Url using oClient.UploadString("myurl", "POST", "MyXml");  I noticed it MyXml is empty the service accepts the request.

Comment: I assumed you added "application/xml" or "application/json" to the request header when making those requests?

Comment: If I add [XmlSerializerFormat] below [OperationContract] it works ??

Comment: Great. What about the json case?

Comment: But, although it accepts the result the person object is null, any ideas why

Comment: I had to change WebMessageBodyStyle.WrappedRequest to WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare, and it is now working.  Thanks.